# How can I define qmake's library search directories?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, qmake

I'm working with MSVC code in Qt Creator, and build this using the MSVC compiler.
My code uses constructions like:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")
```

How Can I instruct qmake, in the `.pro` file, to find these libraries?
I thought that `DEPENDPATH` served this purpose, however this doesn't seem to work.

What should I be using instead?

P.S. Please do not tell me that is not a portable bad code,
I know, that is not portable and that's ok

Answer (score 1):

Qmake has the `LIBS` variable with which you can set search directories, and also even libraries to link. In your case, something like

```
LIBS += -Lpath/to/lib/directory -lmylib
```

would work and alleviate the need for the `#pragma` altogether. Note that although it uses Unix-like syntax (`-L` for library search directories and `-l` for lib names without the `lib` pre- and suffixes), qmake will make sure it does the right thing for MSVC as well.